# All of those bunny rabbits

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Look at this diagram:

=

++=

+=

++=

+=

Can you explain the meaning?

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/5Uhsyc5.png) for those who can't see the emojis.

Comment: Are you sure the [tag:riddle] tag is appropriate?

Comment: Thanks for uploading a picture, I neglected to think about those who might not be able to see emojis. I think you're right about riddle being wrong here, I'll try and change it. I thought it was the blanket tag for puzzles

Comment: @Bass I'm not sure that the enigmatic puzzling tag _quite_ fits, either - kind of on the fence. Any suggestions? Also, welcome to Puzzling.SE, YOus0147, and thanks for posting this puzzle! FWIW, we try to avoid "blanket tags" in general, because they serve no real purpose. I totally understand your mistake, though (it happens _all the time_), and I appreciate your prompt action in removing the tag. Hope to see you again soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 1

> A rabbit alone has no children, and dies without offspring.

Line 5

> Each couple of rabbits has four children.

Line 2

> Three rabbits are two couples. If they are two females and one male, three rabbits can have eight children, because each female can give birth to four childen.

Line 3

> A couple of rabbits do not have offspring if they are of the same gender.

Line 4

> Three rabbits have four children if they are two males and one female.

EDIT: Maybe with this changes?

Comment: Nicely done on ordering it logically! Line 1 and 5 are correctly guessed. Line 2 is almost completely guessed, and Line 3 and 4 are off. You're very close though! You've pretty much got most of it understood already, almost there

Comment: Exactly! You nailed it, well done :)

Comment: may i ask why are the ghosts there? thanks! +1

Comment: Ghosts are rabbits that died without offsprings. May I say "they will not live in the future generations"?

Comment: Pretty much yeah. Ghosts are a way to indicate that those rabbits produce ghost/nothing. It could be an interesting puzzle omitting the ghosts, I think it'd make for a tougher puzzle, which could be fun to explore.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like

> A story.
>
> In the first line, 1 bunny died.
> In the second, 3 rabbits have children (maybe one male and two female I don't
> know), so after this line, they are 8.
> In the third, 2 rabbits died.
> In the line n°4: same as line 2, but they are 4 in the end.
> Last line: 2 rabbits have 2 babies.

Comment: Very interesting guess. It's not supposed to be a story no, but you're right about the resulting rabbits being the children produced. The equations don't have a narrative connection as such, but they do have another connection. I won't mind giving a spoilered hint if you'd like one :)

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't quite fit, it reminds me of

> Conway's game of life, where any cell (rabbit) with less than 2 neighbours dies (ghost), any cell with 3 neighbours reproduces, etc. As I said, not a perfect fit for each individual équation, but maybe with some connection between them ?

Comment: Interesting guess, I can definitely see why you'd suspect that pattern. It's not that sort of sequence I'm looking for. You could say though, however the answer is heavily related with what inspired Conways game of life, so to speak.